# python3 command not found after installing python with pyenv

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I installed a specific version of python with pyenv. When typed `pyenv version` in terminal, i see `3.5.0 (set by /Users/lcherukuri/.python-version)`. But when I typed `python3`, I got `python3 command not found`. How to fix this? pip3 is Also not found

Comment: Is python part of your $PATH? What OS are you on?

Comment: you need to define an alias for the new environment. Like: https://gist.github.com/haridas/4966347

Comment: try 'python' without the 3. It may be that with specific environment python give you python3

Comment: @ArjunAthreya macOS

Comment: @PaulaThomas just `python` works. But it uses system  2.7 version. i need python 3.5.0

Answer (score 8):

If you installed both python 2.x and python 3.x using pyenv, run the following to enable both versions to be found globally (python, python2 and python3 aliases).

Add the specific versions you are using:

```
pyenv global 3.8.3 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 8):

`pyenv` manages shim executables for commands like `python3` and `pip3`. If pyenv's shims aren't available in your shell, it usually means one of two things:

- pyenv isn't fully installed

or

- pyenv shell features aren't active

As your pyenv command is working but the shims aren't, it most likely means the shell features aren't activated. As of writing, the correct way is to ensure the init command output is evaluated. On macOS, you can add the following to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Older installation instructions might not include that step or just have you add pyenv's bin directory to the PATH, which is not enough. If you used pyenv-installer, this step is hinted at in a warning at the end of the installation process.

Comment: This answer deserves an award for the amount of concepts, logic, and context included. It saved me so much struggle. Thank you.

Comment: I needed python 3 (global) and python 2 for a specific app (pyenv local...). Both were installed from pyenv but only python3 command worked. Adding ```eval "$(pyenv init -)" ``` in bash profile helped to use respective global, local versions.
Thanks for sharing useful init command to make both versions work in respective contexts.

Answer (score 3):

`pyenv` is just a Python version manager. It may be able to see a Python 3.X installed even if `python3` isn't installed in your $PATH.

You need to add `python3` to your $PATH. You can see how to do that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html).

By default, MacOS uses `python3` to differentiate between the native pre-installed `python` (which is Python 2.7) and any post-installed Python 3.X distributions. The same goes for `pip` and `pip3`.

From the `pyenv` documentation on managing versions:

> ### Locating the Python Installation
>
> Once pyenv has determined which
> version of Python your application has specified, it passes the
> command along to the corresponding Python installation.
>
> Each Python version is installed into its own directory under $(pyenv
> root)/versions.
>
> For example, you might have these versions installed:
>
> $(pyenv root)/versions/2.7.8/
>
> $(pyenv root)/versions/3.4.2/
>
> $(pyenvroot)/versions/pypy-2.4.0/
>
> As far as pyenv is concerned, version names
> are simply the directories in $(pyenv root)/versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the python3 in path. I also executed `pyenv global 2.x.x 3.x.x`. But I still got the same error.

What eventually worked for me is executing this line in the project root (with whichever version replacing 3.X.X)

`pyenv shell 3.X.X`

Note: This sets the shell specific python version so it's not really a solution to the problem posted. Just a workaround to get python3 working.