# Architecture Not Supported Error when installing nltk with pip on Mac

Tags: python, pip, nltk, macos-catalina

New MacBookPro running Catalina.  I have a virtualenv with no additional libraries installed yet.  When I try to install nltk with `pip3 install nltk`, I get the following long error.  The gist of it being "Architecture Not Supported".

I tried installing with `pip3 install -U` but got a similar failure.  Below is the all of the terminal text beginning with the first error message.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-wheel-vixqiu0k
       cwd: /private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/
  Complete output (114 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
  copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
  copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
  copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
  copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
  running build_ext
  building 'regex._regex' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex_3
  xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex_3/_regex.o
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
  #error Unsupported architecture
   ^
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
  typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
  typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex
  Running setup.py clean for regex
Failed to build regex
Installing collected packages: tqdm, regex, nltk
    Running setup.py install for regex ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-record-2kbtvdvx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/include/site/python3.8/regex
         cwd: /private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/
    Complete output (114 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex_3
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/regex_3/_regex.o
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from regex_3/_regex.c:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-install-3izld5bk/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t3/ccw8mfyj24s1cdsyrwtpb32r0000gp/T/pip-record-2kbtvdvx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/Jayco/projects/passgen/venv/include/site/python3.8/regex Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993071) help?

Comment: Not really.  I have not updated XCode since installing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem with the default installed python. (pip3 install regex)
When using python from brew it worked for me.

Try this:

```
brew install python3
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install nltk
```

or with a virtualenv:

```
brew install python3
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install ntlk
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  I wish I understood why - I had been using the brew-installed python all along.  But specifiying the path worked.

Comment: You can check with `which python3` if the correct python is used.

Answer (score 24):

since the error message shows `#error architecture not supported`, maybe you want to tell pip which architecture you are using.

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3 install nltk
```

please note the `x86_64` argument you specified should match your system's real architecture.

I fixed a similar issue when I tried to install pycairo.

Comment: yes, it works for me as I'm installing regexp.

Comment: worked for me while everything else failed.

Comment: I exhausted trying to install `cartopy` from pip in a virtual environment(py3.8) created by virtualenv. Later, I tried to install it from the source, and your suggestion works for me! `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py install`

Comment: Looks like you can use `uname -m` to get your current architecture.

Comment: This! Worked for me when I needed to install lxml